# Highcharts: only show part of a map

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using a map in HighCharts and sometimes I need to just show a section of the map, not the entire map. I think I could manually do this by zooming into a part of the map but ideally I would like to specify a bounding box with lat/lon coordinates for example. I'm sure this must be possible — in the API there is mention of mapTransforms but I don't know how to use it.
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.mapTransforms

The best in my case would be for HighCharts only to display the parts of the map with data — there is an option in the API to not display all areas (https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.allAreas) but this is not what I want. That option simply doesn't render the parts of the map with no data and I definitely don't want to do that.

An example of an official JSFiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/world-continents

```
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
    ['eu', 0],
    ['oc', 1],
    ['af', 2],
    ['as', 3],
    ['na', 4],
    ['sa', 5]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'custom/world-continents'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-continents.js">World continents</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

What would I do so that the initial map loads on, for example, mainly Europe?

Thanks to anyone who can help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs, where you can find the example: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.MapView#setView

However I think that for your case you should use `zoomBy` feature: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.MapView#zoomBy

Comment: That's perfect — exactly what I need. I'm not sure why I would use setView versus zoomBy but for my purposes, setView does the job perfectly. I use these parameters (in my case): 
map.mapView.setView([4900,7950], -0.3, true, false);
I was confused at first by the Lon/lat array but once I understood that for 'pre-projected' maps you use X/Y values (not sure how they are calculated but I figured out what I needed). And I want no animation so I use false to turn that off. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One of the issues I've realised with this approach is that the maps created seem no longer to be responsive. Normally the HighCharts maps change size depending on the size of the container but with this approach, it no longer seems to be the case. The map size never changes and it's necessary to pan and scroll to see the full map. So even though the solution works well for a fixed width, it doesn't seem to be quite what I need either. I need the map to be responsive. I will post back if I find a way to fix this.

Comment: @pingin - could you reproduce this issue on some online editor?

Comment: I will sure. My workaround for the moment is use keep the zoom quite wide but I will create later a version on jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Even though this approach might work for many scenarios, in my case there is one issue which I haven't been able to fix. Zooming doesn't appear to change the underlying nature of the map, so if you had a map of the World and zoomed into Europe, when you Export it, it still shows a map of the world. I can't see anything in the API that would fix this issue. An example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/exporting/scale/ Zoom in and Export but the original map is still shown.

Comment: The chart is rendering from the scratch while exporting, so this zoom is not saved anywhere, you need to implement logic for it or trigger zoom manually: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e10gxmqw/

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. That's incredibly helpful. Thank you very much — it completely solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zoomTo() to zoom into specific point of your data.

I modified few things

1. mapData = Highcharts.maps["custom/world-continents"].features
   this is from your data js for the data. This gives the map the relevant data
2. Added a loadto function, you can call it wherever you want, this is just for demo, i tried to call it under chart but didn't work out. so you can use document load or ready or after chart load.
3. chart.get('EU').zoomTo()  here chart is the variable and EU "uppercase" is the data point from mapdata. you can use any continent AS AF etc.

Code

```
var data = [
        ['eu', 0],
        ['oc', 1],
        ['af', 2],
        ['as', 3],
        ['na', 4],
        ['sa', 5]
    ];
var mapData = Highcharts.maps["custom/world-continents"].features
    // Create the chart

var chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
  chart: {
    map: 'custom/world-continents',
  },
  . . .
  series: [{
    data: data,
    mapData: mapData,
    allowPointSelect: true,
    states: {
      hover: {
        color: '#BADA55'
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}'
    }
  }]
});


function loadto() {
  chart.get('EU').zoomTo();
}
loadto()
```

You can copy these parts it will work in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's a good solution. I think it's not exactly what I need for this job as I want to arbitrarily set a bounding box and so want to specify lat/lon and a zoom level but I do like your solution and there are other places I can make use of it. So many thanks for the taking the time and effort to answer!